# twisted: how to delete a static resource?

Tags: python-2.7, autobahn, twisted.web, twisted.internet, autobahnws

I have a basic TCP server implemented in twisted, to which a client is connected. The client connects and sends data necessary to start a websocket resource. Using these details sent by the TCP client, I want to add an autobahn websocket resource as a child under a twisted web resource. **and when the client disconnects, I want to remove this child from the twisted web resource.** please suggest, what should be the best way to implement this? Can I use resource.delEntity(child)?

so far, the code looks like this:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory, WebSocketServerProtocol
from autobahn.twisted.resource import WebSocketResource

class ProtoPS(WebSocketServerProtocol):
  def onMessage(self,payload,isBinary):
    if not isBinary:
        print("Text message received: {}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))
    self.sendMessage(payload,isBinary)

class BaseResource:
  def __init__(self,proto,vid):
    self.vid = vid
    self.factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
    self.factory.protocol = proto
    self.resource = WebSocketResource(self.factory)
    wsroot.putChild(self.vid,self.resource)

class BackendProto(Protocol):
  def __init__(self):
    self.SERVICEMAP = {}

  def dataReceived(self,data):
    msg = json.loads(data)
    if ('cmd' in msg) and (msg['cmd'] == "create"):
         self.vid = msg['client']['id']
         self.SERVICEMAP[self.vid] = BaseResource(ProtoPS,self.vid)

  def connectionLost(self,reason):
    wsroot.delEntity(self.vid)
    del self.SERVICEMAP[self.vid]

class BackendFactory(Factory):
  protocol = BackendProto

if __name__ == '__main__':
  reactor.listenTCP(8081,BackendFactory())
  wsroot = Data("","text/plain")
  wssite = Site(wsroot)
  reactor.listenTCP(9000,wssite)
```